# Python places escape symbols in the Swagger web services response

Tags: python, flask, swagger

I have an store procedure Oracle that returns a variable type CLOB with information in JSON format. That variable caught her in a Python
and I return it for a Web Service. The store procedure output is of this style:

```
{"role":"Proof_Rol","identification":"31056235002761","class":"Proof_Clase","country":"ARGENTINA","stateOrProvince":"Santa Fe","city":"Rosario","locality":"Rosario","streetName":"Brown","streetNr":"2761","x":"5438468,710153","y":"6356634,962204"}
```

But at the Python service exit it is shown as follows:

```
{"Atributos": "{\"role\":\"Proof_Rol\",\"identification\":\"31056235002761\",\"class\":\"Proof_Clase\",\"country\":\"ARGENTINA\",\"stateOrProvince\":\"Santa Fe\",\"city\":\"Rosario\",\"locality\":\"Rosario\",\"streetName\":\"Brown\",\"streetNr\":\"2761\",\"x\":\"5438468,710153\",\"y\":\"6356634,962204\"}"}
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to prevent the escape characters from entering that string at the exit of the service?

Part of my Python Code is:

```
api = Api(APP, version='1.0', title='attributes API',
          description='Attibute Microservice\n'
                      'Conection DB:' + db_str + '\n'
                                                  'Max try:' + limite)
 ns = api.namespace('attributes', description='Show descriptions of an object')

md_respuesta = api.model('attributes', {
    'Attribute': fields.String(required=True, description='Attribute List')
})

class listAtriClass:
    Attribute = None

@ns.route('/<string:elementId>')
@ns.response(200, 'Success')
@ns.response(404, 'Not found')
@ns.response(429, 'Too many request')
@ns.param('elementId', 'Id Element (ej:31056235002761)')
class attibuteClass(Resource):
    @ns.doc('attributes')
    @ns.marshal_with(md_respuesta)
    def post(self, elementId):
        try:
            cur = database.db.cursor()
            listOutput = cur.var(cx_Oracle.CLOB)
            e, l = cur.callproc('attributes.get_attributes', (elementId, listOutput))
        except Exception as e:
            database.init()
            if database.db is not None:
                log.err('Reconection OK')
                cur = database.db.cursor()
                listOutput = cur.var(cx_Oracle.CLOB)
                e, l = cur.callproc('attributes.get_attributes', (elementId, listOutput))
                print(listOutput)
            else:
                log.err('Conection Fails')
                listOutput = None
        result = listAtriClass()
        result.Attribute =listOutput.getvalue()
        print(result.Attribute)
        return result, 200
```

Answer (score 3):

`Attribute` is defined to render as a [`fields.String`](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fields.String) but actually it should be defined to render as [`fields.Nested`](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#advanced-nested-field).

```
attribute_fields = {
    "role": fields.String,
    "identification": fields.String,
    "class": fields.String,
    # ...you get the idea.
}

md_respuesta = api.model('attributes', {
    'Attribute': fields.Nested(attribute_fields)
})
```

**Update for flask-restplus**

In `flask-restplus`, a nested field must also register a model.

```
attribute_fields = api.model('fields', {
    "role": fields.String,
    "identification": fields.String,
    "class": fields.String,
    # ...you get the idea.
})
```

Another way is to inline `attribute_fields` instead of registering a separate model for it.

```
md_respuesta = api.model('attributes', {
    'Attribute': {
        'role': fields.String,
        'identification': fields.String,
        'class': fields.String,
        # ...you get the idea.
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks for you response.
I put your suggest, but now i received this message in the webservice:

No API definition provided.

Comment: I working with this libraries:
import cx_Oracle
import json
from attributes import APP
import log
import graypy
import database
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, fields

Comment: How do I assign the CLOB to the variables of the python?